# Virtual microphone and python

Tags: python, microphone

I'm on Lubuntu 19.10 and I would like to create a virtual microphone that can be used from other software (eg. the browser) as an audio source and pipe audio to it in real time using a python script.

Since now I tried different solution and I now have a virtual device named `MicOutput` which I created using the following command:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=MicOutput sink_properties=device.description="Virtual_Microphone_Output"
```

How can I send audio to it using Python?

**EDIT**:
I solved as showed in the answer below, but how can I change at least the output of the script to the virtual microphone automatically when I launch it? I mean there is a command to execute in terminal to do that?

Answer (score 3):

I solved changing manually the output of the python script and the input of the web application to the virtual microphone created with the previous command, using the `pavucontrol` or `pulseaudio` GUI.

I add some images to be more clear.

[image: To direct audio output from python script to the virtual microphone]
To direct audio output from python script to the virtual microphone

[image: To use monitor of the virtual microphone as source for a specific tab in firefox]
To use monitor of the virtual microphone as source for a specific tab in firefox

Comment: Thank you so much @Paa. That helped so much!! :)